# Creating new calculation to sum a Dax Calculated Measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a promised hours calculation that looks at two dates (Coalesce) and gets the number of weeks in the month and then multiply it by the max promised hours for an employee which has a row for every week of the month. The employee could have 5 rows for every entry a week and the promised hours shows up the same as for example 40 for that week, thus why I have to take the max instead of do a sum. But at the end I need to show the total number of promised hours per week for whatever timeframe is chosen in the date slicer per employee.

```
Promised Hours Calc = CALCULATE(WEEKNUM(Max([CoalesceActualStart_AbsenceStart]),1)-WEEKNUM(MIN([CoalesceActualStart_AbsenceStart]),1))*MAX(FSLData[PromisedHours])
```

I then need it to do a sum for every employee on the above calculation.
I am getting all sorts of errors trying to do a sum on the calculation as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

What you write is confusing and incomprehensible. That's why you get the errors. As soon as you are able to formulate your problem in such a way that others can understand it, you will understand it yourself and the errors will go away.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have this working in SSRS (our other reporting system). I know what I'm after and can write it in SQL. I'm sorry that you don't understand what I'm asking, but it is pretty simple. I need to be able to sum on the calculation I provided above. Plain and simple...